# Cosmic Inflation and the Distance between an Electron(s) and Their Respective Nucleus

Tags: electrons, nuclear-physics, cosmological-inflation

If cosmic inflation is indeed occurring, doe this apply to all space/time?  What about the space between an electron and the nucleus?  Seems to me if that space is also expanding, atoms should cease to exist.  Or are quantum spaces somehow exempt from inflation?

Comment: Hi Ross, welcome to PSE. This question is answered above, but inflation is distinct from expansion in cosmology terminology, to be long winded about it.

Answer (score 0):

[Cosmic inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) is a popular but disputed theory of the exponential expansion of space in the first tiny fraction of a second after the presumed Big Bang singularity. No atoms existed at this time, as the universe was far too hot - in fact, there weren't even hadrons (such as protons).

This inflationary epoch was followed by the quark epoch, when the universe was filled with a dense, hot quark–gluon plasma. It was only several epochs later, in the [photon epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_epoch) (about 10 seconds after the Big Bang) that atomic nuclei were created.

Inflation is different to the [metric expansion of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space), which is the increase in the distance between two distant parts of the universe over time. This metric expansion is ongoing and is currently accelerating.

If this acceleration continues, the [Big Rip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip) cosmological model proposes that in the very far future atoms will indeed be torn apart and cease to exist.

Comment: My bad, meant expansion.  So as it is articulated above, the EM force holds the atom together, much like galaxies are held together by gravity, even though expansion is occurring.   At what point will the expansive force overcome the EM force?  Overcome gravity?  A trillion years?